# How to select one of many children inside a DIV

Tags: jquery

I have this Tree

```
<div id="chatRooms">
<div class="chatRoom">Lala</div>
<div class="chatRoom">Lolo</div>
<div class="chatRoom">Lili</div>
</div>
```

`$("#chatRooms").children(".chatRoom");` will select all the children, I want to select only 1, regardless of the `.html()` of these children, this is just an example, how can I do it?

Comment: Which one do you want to select?

Comment: random selection is intended?

Comment: These .chatRoom divs will be removed and appended many times ( parting room and joining room) so yes I want to select a random chatroom after existing another room..just like IRC

Comment: I am afraid, that I cannot really follow here. Usually one intentionally joins a chat room in IRC. Unless you are trying to write some bot that randomly joins chat rooms from a list of rooms, this does not seem to make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#chatRooms").children(".chatRoom")[2]; // returns DOM element
                                             not Jquery, must be rewrapped
```

or

```
 $("#chatRooms").children(".chatRoom").eq(2); // returns JQuery element
```

or

```
 $("#chatRooms > .chatRoom:eq(2)"); // 0-based index!
```

or

```
 $("#chatRooms > .chatRoom:nth-child(3)"); // 1-based index! and other differences
```

for example :)

There are also other options with **selectors** (as `$("#chatRooms .chatRoom:first")`) and with Jquery Functions

```
  $("#chatRooms").children(".chatRoom").last()
```

**Edit:** expanded answer also with observations of Ofir Baruch and  Esben Skov Pedersen.

Comment: note when using [2] the object is no longer jquery wrapped which means it must be wrapped with $() again for using jqeury functions.

Comment: And I think it happened with me because It only worked once, it doesn't work again

Comment: @AliBassam Just, as Esben says, rewrap the element with $(element) or consider using `.eq(n)`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `:eq` operator, `:eq` will refer to the index of the element you want to select.

Comment: consider the difference between `:eq` to `nth-child` (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

Answer (score 0):

if you rely on random selection a lot you could get this jquery plugin which will introduce the :random filter:
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-random-filter/

then you can have something like

```
$("#chatRooms").children(".chatRoom:random");
```

OR you could use something like this which does not need another plugin

```
var count = $("#chatRooms > .chatRoom").length;
var random = Math.Round(Math.random()*count);
$("#chatRooms > .chatRoom").eq(random);
```

Comment: added another way without the use of yet another plugin.